# How many squares can be formed from n equidistant points in a circle?

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to find a general formula for finding the number of squares that can be formed from n points that are equidistant from each other and placed on the circumference of a circle, I started with n=4 for which there is just 1, for n= 6 I found 1 with n = 8 points on the circle my answer is 2, so I just believe in the hindsight that for n points on the circle's circumference the answer should be $$n/4$$ am I correct on this?

This is the exact question out of the book -:

[image]

also it would be great if you could provide answers for the other parts so that I can confirm them :), if convenient.

Comment: I reckon, for $n=6$, we do not get any squares. Please do clarify by writing a picture. Square is formable iff $4|n$ and $n\ge 4$. Further, there are $\frac{n-4}{4}+1$ distinct squares.

Comment: sure lemme post a picture.

Comment: If you have more than $3$ points they cannot be equidistant from each other. What do you mean by 'equidistant from each other'? Maybe you are saying that they form a regular polygon inscribed in the circumference?

Comment: did you mean, uniformly spaced on the circumference?

Comment: yes, they are uniformly space along the circumference of the circle

Comment: @talegari: yes for n=6 there are no squares possible my bad my mistake, but if n=8 then we have 2 squares, so does this rule hold in general like if n is a multiple of 4 then n/4 is the number of squares that can be formed?

Comment: @Crostul I reckon the points should be vertices of a regular $n$-gon

Comment: When you say a square is "formed from" a given set of points, you mean that all four vertices of the square are members of that set, correct? This seems to be the obvious interpretation but perhaps it needs to be clarified for some people.

Comment: Note that ${n-4\over4}+1$ is just a complicated way of writing $n/4$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:
The following simple observation will help.

If there is a square inscribed in the circle, its diagonals must pass through the center.

So, this is only possible if for a given point, there are points at anglular distance $\pi/2$, $\pi$ and $3\pi/2$ from it, which is possible only when $n$ is a multiple of 4.

So your formula $n/4$ is correct only for multiples of 4.

For the other values, it is not valid. Rather answer = ??

Comment: so I guess my answer is correct for n=8?

Comment: Yes for $n=8$, your formula works.